# How to model compartment chemical concentration with permeation through a membrane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

Suppose we have one chemical species $V$ and two compartments in which $V$ can be, $A$ and $B$, with volumes $\Omega_A$ and $\Omega_B$ respectively, where $\Omega_A < \Omega_B$.

Compartments $A$ and $B$ are separated by a biological membrane. The permeability of the membrane with respect $V$ is $P$cm $\text{s}^{-1}$. Let us say the membrane has thickness $\varepsilon$ cm.

See diagram below.

[image]

I wish not to model diffusion or any spatial variation, I am assuming well mixed. I will represent the concentration of $V$ by $v$ with units $M=\text{mol}{L^{-1}}$. $v_A(t)$ and $v_B(t)$ represent the concentration of $V$ in $A$ and $B$ respectively, where $t$ is time.

I am going to represent movement from $A$ to $B$ by a 'reaction', similary for $B$ to $A$. My question is how from $P$ do I describe the rates of the  reactions $Q_{AB}$ and $Q_{BA}$ from $P$ (and $\Omega_A,\Omega_B$ as these are concentrations?) so that the following makes sense:

$$\frac{dv_A}{dt}=Q_{BA}v_B-Q_{AB}v_A$$
$$\frac{dv_B}{dt}=-(Q_{BA}v_B-Q_{AB}v_A)$$

Comment: First one needs to understand what $P$ means for the movement of a stream of particles.

Comment: Would you mind explaining? That was a concept I was struggling with.

Comment: Assuming the membrane would pose no influence on $V$ passing between compartments $A$ and $B$ then we have plain diffusion process: the transfer of $V$ would be driven by the system to reach uniform concentration and the time development of the concentrations is connected to the velocity of the $V$ particles along concentration gradients. $P$ in some way will influence this. So you need to look up the definition of that quantity and the model behind it.

Comment: The long term solution would of course be uniform concentration. My question is if we wanted to the model the initial behaviour using these 2 equations of the system given an initial conditions what information about the membrane would we need to construct $Q_{AB}$ and $Q_{BA}$?

Comment: $$Q_{AB}=Q_{BA}=P/\varepsilon$$

Comment: @Did Thanks for this! Would I be able to ask you to justify this?

Comment: Definitions vary, see [there](http://mathbench.umd.edu/modules/cell-processes_diffmembrane/page07.htm) for an alternative, but the units of your P leave no choice. The idea is always that the exchange rates are proportional to the difference of the concentrations and that the permeability measures this coefficient of proportionality.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful and exactly what I needed!